# How to create my own event source in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am new to Mac development. I know if I implement a method as IBAction and it will be shown in the interface builder to be connected with an event source from an UI object, such as a button or a menu item.

Now I want to mimic a button object. It has an entry shown in the "Sent Actions" block of interface builder. It can be connected to the "Received Actions" block of another object. Is it doable?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but you might want to provide a bit more information - what is it exactly that you want to accomplish? And why have you chosen that road? Also, what you tried?

Comment: Do you necessarily want to re-implement the mechanism from scratch? If not you could just inherit from NSResponder and override it's methods.

Answer (score 1):

Inherit your custom class from `NSControl` or `NSButton` (which itself is a `NSControl` subclass). The `NSControl` class implements the target-action pattern you are describing. Interface Builder will let you connect any `NSControl` instance to an action method and let you specify.

In your subclass, call `[self sendAction:[self action] to:[self target]]` whenever you want your control to send an event that then causes the associated action methods to fire.